# Should I use an epoxy finish on a high traffic hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

We tried refinishing our very old hardwood floors last year but they haven't held up that well.  The floor receives very heavy walking traffic.  Perhaps two coats was not enough?  We are thinking about just buffing the floor and throwing down another coat of Synteko.  Additionally, a friend recommended that we use a two-part epoxy to cope with the heavy traffic our floor receives.  Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: The other approach would be to cut down on the wear on that floor, eg by having everyone leave their shoes at the door, getting caps for the dog's claws, and the like. Of course there's no reason you can't attack the problem from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Epoxy solutions in general last longer than polys.  They do come with residential drawbacks too in that they are harder to patch and don't handle temperature differences as well.

I personally have used [bona industrial](http://www.bona.com/en/Professional/BonaSystem/Industrial-Coatings/) for high traffic areas.  I would really look into the industrial products so you don't feel the need of yearly upkeep.